Metastable states of the 1D Ising model
When studying the formation of domains in a 1D Ising ring, I find transitions (for a lack of a better word) that I struggle to name or explain. My Monte Carlo simulation is constructed as follows:
1.We only consider Kawasaki dynamics and each spin is connected to its $R$ closest neighbors, resulting in the energy difference between states 2 (changed) and 1 (unchanged) calculated as:
$$\Delta E=\left(\sum_{j=i_1-R; \\j\neq i_1}^{i_1+R}s(j)-\sum_{j=i_2-R; \\j\neq i_2}^{i_2+R}s(j)\right)\left(s(i_1)-s(i_2)\right).$$

The probability of chance is given by the Metropolis algorithm
$$P=\min(1, e^{-\Delta E /T}).$$

Random numbers are generated with $\texttt{mt19937_64}$ for C++.


I get so confused on why I get this. The $x$-axis is position on the ring and $y$-axis is MC step. Position is yellow if spin is +1 and black otherwise. I was actually looking for states as observed in the left yellow region, but the "change of state" or just merging of two branches in the right side doesn't seem to make any sense to me. Is this sudden change in behavior a cause of energy not being conserved and then perhaps a numerical error? If so, where could it be? Or did I make wrong assumptions about energy? Or maybe it is right?


What is $R$ in this simulation?

It's a parameter defining the number of neighbours to the left and to the right. So if R=2, each spin has 4 neighbours.

Yes, but what value of $R$ did you use in this simulation?

It's 20, so as you can see it reaches the end of one band till the beginnig of the other. It seems like merging of two branches is not only possible but expected given the dynamics, it's the sudden way it happens that seems wrong.
